# What currency is the Developer Survey's Salary field in?

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

The [Methodology](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#methodology) section in the survey results says:

> We converted salaries given in the 38 most-frequently-used currencies to [dollars / Euros / pounds sterling] using the exchange rate that prevailed mid-way through the survey field period.

Do the Methodology notes apply to the downloadable dataset, or does that have raw(er) data?

If they do, which currency is the `Salary` field really in?

I can make a reasonable guess based on the data, but it would be nice to have an explicit answer. I couldn't find one in the official survey results or in the PDF included with the data.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Salary](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#salary) section, it is specified that USD was used:

> DevOps and machine learning specialists tend to command the largest salaries globally. Please see our Methodology section for information on how we converted local currencies used by respondents to **U.S. dollars**.

But still, looks like the methodology is not properly edited.